# Arduino ethernet communication

Tags: arduino, communication, ethernet

Is it possible to get sensor output from Arduino via Ethernet connection and to send data to Arduino via Ethernet?

So basically can "replace" serial port with Ethernet port?

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this is with an Arduino Ethernet shield, a small hardware module that plugs into your Arduino board:

- http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield

**Updated:**

One very common approach for client to server communication would be to use HTTP over TCP/IP. See this example on the Ardunio site of a simple client on an Ardunio connecting with a server (in this case google):

- http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient

For your use case you can simply create your own server and modify the example to send data to it.

Alternatively you can skip the HTTP part and just use sockets - there is an open source example here:

- https://github.com/billroy/socket.io-arduino-client

Comment: I already have that. so if I connect the Arduino via Ethernet to an ethernet hub, and I know his static IP address, can I get output from arduino in my c++ program over IP address?